# Add timestamp to field automatically in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I created a small database in PostgreSQL to manage the data for my thesis. I just started with Postgres, so this is probably a newbie question. I added a column in several tables, that is supposed to hold the last update of a certain field. One of these tables looks like this (The column relevant here would be *lastupdate*:

```
-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public.finds;

CREATE TABLE public.finds (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    id_investigations int8 NOT NULL,
    quote_short varchar NULL,
    "group" varchar NULL,
    "type" varchar NULL,
    subtype varchar NULL,
    description varchar NULL,
    "number" int4 NULL,
    certainty bool NULL,
    note varchar NULL,
    checked bool NULL,
    lastupdate timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT finds_check_group CHECK ((("group")::text = ANY ((ARRAY['Keramik'::character varying, 'Waffe'::character varying, 'Werkzeug'::character varying, 'Schmuck'::character varying])::text[]))),
    CONSTRAINT finds_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT id_investigations FOREIGN KEY (id_investigations) REFERENCES investigations(id)
);

-- Permissions

ALTER TABLE public.finds OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.finds TO postgres;
```

I would like the *lastupdate* to take the current timestamp upon edit. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You need a trigger for that

Comment: When you say, "upon edit", what do you mean by edit? Are you writing an application that uses PostgreSQL as a backend and has the edits implemented as PostgreSQL UPDATE statements under the covers? Or is there no application and the UPDATEs are issued directly by users (or at least you want to cover those as well)?

Comment: @AndriyM I am not writing an application, I just use PostgreSQL as the backend for a geographic information system for my thesis. So the only user will be me. Currently I am doing all the edits directly in PostgreSQL, mostly via DBeaver and QGIS.

Comment: Ah, got it, in this case it still is an application that generates the UPDATEs but you've got no control over it and hence no control over the generated commands, I see. Looks like a trigger *is* the most optimal solution for you after all. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION last_upd_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.lastupdate := current_timestamp;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER last_upd_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON finds
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE last_upd_trig();
```

Comment: I understand the code, but it throws an error when I try to run it as  an SQL-script in pgAdmin:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOR"
ZEILE 9:    FOR EACH ROW
            
SQL state: 42601
Character: 201
```

Comment: Probably my typo. It should be `ON finds`, not `OF finds`.

Comment: Ok. The script works and the trigger appears in the list as it should. But when I put in data and try to save I get the message "ERROR: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN KONTEXT: PL/pSQL function last_upd_trig()."

Comment: Another embarrassing omission - forgot the `RETURN` in the trigger function.

Comment: Now it works. Thank you! Note that you will need to get rid of the old trigger, if you want to use a slightly modified version of with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to solve this problem is a trigger.
This is the official documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-trigger.html

See this post too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556474/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-timestamp-in-postgresql

Comment: Thanks. Note especially the answer by Parichay Mo at your second link. This does not update automatically, but using now() as default for a timestamp field is a good solution for fields like createdat or similar.